# Xcode UITabBarController: Make Two tabs point to same ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I built a simple app to view movie listing from rotten tomatoes(as a part of learning ios development)https://raw.githubusercontent.com/koldkoder/movie_listing/master/rotten_tomatoes.gif

I am trying to add tab control. One tab would list current box office movies, and second tab to list movies out on DVD recently. Both Views are exactly same, just they get data from different api endpoint. I want to use UITabBarController to implement this functionality. But i dont want to create two duplicate Viewcontrollers, instead use one for both the purpose. What is the right way of doing this, using storyboard, and code.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straight forward. Create one UIViewController that takes a view type param in initializer like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, MediaViewType) {
    MediaViewTypeBoxOffice = 0,
    MediaViewTypeDVD
};

- (id)initWithViewType:(MediaViewType)iViewType;
```

In the implementation file, handle your view & functionality based on passed view type. Then add your view controller's instances to `UITabBarController`:

```
MyMediaViewController *vc1 = [MyMediaViewController alloc] initWithViewType: MediaViewTypeBoxOffice];
MyMediaViewController *vc2 = [MyMediaViewController alloc] initWithViewType: MediaViewTypeDVD];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[vc1, vc2];
```

Comment: i currently have one ViewController.swift class and i have associated the swift class to a viewController i created using storyboard. As per your approach shall i remove the storyboard controller and only use code to define my view controllers?

Comment: That is fine. You can still follow the above mentioned approach. Control the content inside view by `ViewController.swift ` and instantiate them through code as I said. Instantiating a VC from storyboard would have different syntax though.