# two tabs of UITabbarController pointing to same viewcontrollers

Tags: tabs, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller, tabbar

I am working on an application using swift and storyboard layout. Can you please suggest me the way how can I point two different tabs of UITabbarController to same UIViewControllers embedded in UINavigationController.

[Xcode UITabBarController: Make Two tabs point to same ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625898/xcode-uitabbarcontroller-make-two-tabs-point-to-same-viewcontroller) does not work because I have many tabs in my UITabbarController and I want to do by using storyboards.

thanks.